# How can I cascade field display formatters?

Tags: 7, media, entities

I need to display a thumbnail of my images and the count of its downloads below the thumbnail.

I am using these modules:

1. CCK
2. FileField
3. ImageField
4. ImageCache
5. DownloadCount

and I think I need something like cascading these two formatter:

1. Generic files with download count (comes from DownloadCount)
2. examination_question_image image linked to image (comes from imagecache where examination_question_image is my "Preset Name")

Is there any module or anything else for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the Media module. I think it will solve your problems.